# How to add multiple flowports?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am new to Enterprise Architect. I am trying to define an architecture and I need to add around 100 flowports in a block property with the same properties. The name of the flowports will follow a sequence like A1, A2, A3...A100. Is there any way to define with a couple of clicks or a macro array of multiple flowports?

Thinking of adding them one by one is making me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script to do that, and use JavaScript, JScript of VB. [This is the relevant entry](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.2/automation/the_scripter_window.html) in the user manual.